# Read parquet folder from blob storage

Tags: python, pandas, azure-blob-storage, parquet

I am usually writing and reading parquet files saved from pandas (pyarrow engine) to blob storage in a way described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351478/how-to-read-parquet-files-from-azure-blobs-into-pandas-dataframe).
Generally my read function looks like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
def read_blob(blobname, conn_str, container):
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(conn_str)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(
        container=container_name)
    downloaded_blob = container_client.download_blob(blobname)
    bytes_io = BytesIO(downloaded_blob.readall())
    res = pd.read_parquet(bytes_io)
    return res
```

This works but when I try to download segmented .parquet that looks like a folder I get following error:
`ArrowInvalid: Could not open Parquet input source '': Parquet file size is 0 bytes`
I have verified that there is nothing from with that parquet by downloading it manually from blob storage and then pathing this parquet-folder path into pandas. It reads ok.

The trouble occurs when I try to download such parquet-folder through BytesIO. How can I read it ?

Answer (score 1):

***I have tried to read segmented parquet file in my Azure storage account and got the results below:-***

I have uploaded one segmented parquet file which is acting as a Directory in my Azure blob Storage refer below:-

[image]

[image]

I have used **fastparquet** library with **BytesIO** to read the segmented parquet file in my python code.

**Code:-**

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
import io
import pandas as pd
import fastparquet

# Connect to your blob storage account
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage-account-name>;AccountKey=<account-key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")

# Get the container client for your container (assuming your container is named "parquet")
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client("<container-name>")

# List all blobs in the "folder" that corresponds to the segmented parquet files
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="eg-sample.parquet<yoursegmented-parquetfilename>")

# Download each blob and read it into a pandas dataframe using fastparquet
dfs = []
for blob in blob_list:
    # Download the blob contents into a BytesIO object
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob)
    blob_content = blob_client.download_blob()
    blob_content_bytes = blob_content.content_as_bytes()
    bytes_io = io.BytesIO(blob_content_bytes)

    # Read the parquet file contents into a pandas dataframe using fastparquet
    pf = fastparquet.ParquetFile(io.BytesIO(blob_content_bytes), open_with=io.BytesIO)
    df = pf.to_pandas()

    # Append the dataframe to the list of dataframes
    dfs.append(df)


# Concatenate all the dataframes into a single dataframe
full_df = pd.concat(dfs)
print(full_df)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that sure is helpfull but did not work for me since those segmented parquet files I am using are made with snappy compression and as a result of this they contain files besides .parquet. It would be readable with pd.read_parquet() tho but not with loop over blob names