# How to read parquet files from Azure Blobs into Pandas DataFrame with columns projection on server-side?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, parquet, projection, pyarrow

Following this question: [How to read parquet files from Azure Blobs into Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351478/how-to-read-parquet-files-from-azure-blobs-into-pandas-dataframe)

Is it possible to perform a column projection on the parquet file at server level before downloading it to be more efficient? I.e. I would like to filter only desidered columns before downloading the file.

At the moment I am connecting to Azure services only by a connection string if that helps and using the Python Client library.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to perform a column projection on the parquet file at server level before downloading it to be more efficient? I.e. I would like to filter only desired columns before downloading the file.

To download the desired column from the parquet file in Azure blob storage, you can use the below Python code:

**Code:**

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import pandas as pd 

# Set up the BlobServiceClient
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string('your connection string')

# Get a reference to the Parquet file in Azure Blob Storage
blob_container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('test1')
blob_client = blob_container_client.get_blob_client('samplepar.parquet')

# Define the list of columns to read from the Parquet file
columns = ['title', 'salary', 'birthdate', 'id1', 'id2']
columns_query = ", ".join([f"[{column}]" for column in columns])
query = f"SELECT {columns_query} FROM BlobStorage"
with open("sample.parquet1", "wb") as file:
    blob_client.download_blob().download_to_stream(file)

table = pq.read_table("sample1.parquet")
available_columns = [column for column in columns if column in table.column_names]
print(available_columns)
if available_columns:
    table = table.select(available_columns)
    df = table.to_pandas()
    print(df)
else:
    print("Error: None of the specified columns are present in the Parquet file.")
```

**Output:**

```
['title', 'salary', 'birthdate']
                      title     salary  birthdate
0          Internal Auditor   49756.53   3/8/1971
1             Accountant IV  150280.17  1/16/1968
2       Structural Engineer  144972.51   2/1/1960
3    Senior Cost Accountant   90263.05   4/8/1997
```

[image]

**Downloaded File:**

[image]

Comment: How are the variables columns_query query useful in your example?

Comment: How do I check if a column exists before actually asking for it?

Comment: Just to make sure, does this code perform the column projection at server side (before downloading the file) or at client side (after the download)?

Comment: **How do I check if a column exists before actually asking for it?** --Do you need to project only the existing columns and ignore other non-existing columns?

Comment: I think I do. I have no a-priori knowledge of the list of blobs to download (in the initial related answer) nor of the existing columns of each blob. I have the information of only the desired columns and all the possible existing blobs (built from a-priori knowledge). So I try to download each blob and I wish for each to filter for the desired columns if existing, otherwise ignore them (and download only those which exist).

Comment: @LucaM Check the updated answer if you need to ignore other non-existing columns and also it will print the available columns.

Comment: Thank you but does your solution actually do the pruning server-side, i.e. before actually downloading the file? Also is pq.read_table free of resources from the returned binary stream to "arrow" memory? I'm asking because the checking and filtering of columns is performed after the read_table(). What I wish I could do is to "inspect the metadata of the parquet file at server-side, filter it with the desired columns, and then actually downloading the parquet file with only the desired columns"

Comment: Thank you, for the sake of my learning, would you mind sharing the source of information where I can read how this pruning is done server-side? Is there a page on the arrow documentation maybe? I checked the pandas documentation unsuccessfully.